# Devise: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I create a new user with an existing username I get this error:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username

I do get an error message for everything else (already used email, uncorresponding passwords).

How can I make it return an error that shows up on the page, just like the others, instead of a crashing error.

I have all the default devise setting haven't changed a thing.

Thank you for the help.

EDITED:
This is the page where I create my user:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {class: "form-horizontal form-user form1"}) do |f| %>
       <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :username, class: "control-label mr" %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :username, class: "text-field form-control", html: {spellcheck: "false"} %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email, class: "control-label mr" %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: "text-field form-control", html: {spellcheck: "false"} %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password, class: "control-label ml" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: "text-field form-control", html: {autocomplete: "off"} %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password", class: "control-label ml" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "text-field form-control", html: {autocomplete: "off"} %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="center">
            <br><%= f.submit "Next", class: " btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <% end %>
```

Comment: Have you added a place to display flash messages already?

Comment: Edited: Added the embedded ruby code I use.

Comment: It seems that you don't have a validation in the model for the `username` and the error is returned from the database where the unique constraint is placed. Do you have the validation? If not add it.